# Array: Storing Objects or References

Tags: c++

As a Java developer I have the following C++ question.

If I have objects of type A and I want to store a collection of them in an array, 
then should I just store pointers to the objects or is it better to store the object itself?

In my opinion it is better to store pointers because:
1) One can easily remove an object, by setting its pointer to null
2) One saves space.

Comment: depends on the usage and container..

Comment: I think with "references" you mean pointers. References in C++ cannot be set to null, and you cannot define an array of references anyway.

Comment: container is an array, and objects may be added and deleted during runtime

Comment: given that you replace "references" with "pointers" then yes, storing the pointers in the array would let you set them to null and would save space in the array anyway.

Comment: @Nerdtron: However, you'd still need to manage the object's lifetimes somehow, and the overall memory usage would be greater (the objects themselves, plus the pointers in the array).

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, the object lifetime needs to be managed but storing points to objects in an array doesn't necessarily imply the array owns the objects, the array might be referring to objects owned elsewhere so the lifetime management may be a separate task entirely from whats done with the array.  Also, you're right that the overall memory usage would be greater due to the pointers which is why I clarified that you'd only be saving space in the array itself.  If you have large objects which could be in the array multiple places would be an example where that might help.

Comment: When dealing with dynamic arrays, storing pointers instead of values "wastes" a pointer for each element of the array, but "saves" a value for each element in the capacity of the array.  So for large objects, where you can not reliably keep `capacity()` and `size()` close, and array of pointers can still be a space savings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pointers or just the objects?

You can't put references in an array in C++. You can make an array of pointers, but I'd still prefer a container and of actual objects rather than pointers because:

1. No chance to leak, exception safety is easier to deal with.
2. It isn't less space - if you store an array of pointers you need the memory for the object plus the memory for a pointer.

The only times I'd advocate putting pointers (or smart pointers would be better) in a container (or array if you must) is when your object isn't copy construable and assignable (a requirement for containers, pointers always meet this) or you need them to be polymorphic. E.g.

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
  virtual void it() {}
};

struct bar : public foo {
  int a;
  virtual void it() {}
}; 

int main() {
  std::vector<foo> v;
  v.push_back(bar()); // not doing what you expected! (the temporary bar gets "made into" a foo before storing as a foo and your vector doesn't get a bar added)
  std::vector<foo*> v2;
  v2.push_back(new bar()); // Fine
}
```

If you want to go down this road [boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) might be of interest because they do all of the hard work for you.

## Removing from arrays or containers.

Assigning `NULL` doesn't cause there to be any less pointers in your container/array, (it doesn't handle the `delete` either), the size remains the same but there are now pointers you can't legally dereference. This makes the rest of your code more complex in the form of extra if statements and prohibits things like:

```
// need to go out of our way to make sure there's no NULL here
std::for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(), std::mem_fun(&foo::it));
```

I really dislike the idea of allowing `NULL`s in sequences of pointers in general because you quickly end up burying all the real work in a sequence of conditional statements. The alternative is that `std::vector` provides an `erase` method that takes an iterator so you can write:

```
v2.erase(v2.begin());
```

to remove the first or `v2.begin()+1` for the second. There's no easy "erase the nth element" method though on `std::vector` because of the time complexity - if you're doing lots of erasing then there are other containers which might be more appropriate.

For an array you can simulate erasing with:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
  std::copy(arr, arr+len, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // remove 2nd element, without preserving order:
  std::swap(arr[1], arr[len-1]);
  len -= 1;
  std::copy(arr, arr+len, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // and again, first element:
  std::swap(arr[0], arr[len-1]);
  len -= 1;
  std::copy(arr, arr+len, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

preserving the order requires a series of shuffles instead of a single swap, which nicely illustrates the complexity of erasing that `std::vector` faces. Of course by doing this you've just reinvented a pretty big wheel a whole lot less usefully and flexibly than a standard library container would do for you for free!

Comment: Also "removing" an object by setting a pointer to null is not natural and adds unnecessary complexity to the code.

Comment: 1) moving the actual objects could be costly (for example if you insert into the middle of a vector) 2) you cannot do polymorphic container with the actual objects.

Comment: @kbok the but how would you remove an object from an array?

Comment: @yi_h - good point about the copy constructor and polymorphic things - I added a mention about copy constructable and assignable requirements for containers and an example of where polymorphic matters.

Comment: @kbok - remove is trivial with the right container. With an array you move it to the right most position with a swap and then pretend the array is one element smaller. I'd much prefer the container for that though.

Comment: @user695652 If you want to remove objects from a container, then an array is not what you need.

Comment: @Als - true, I'll fix that one

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are confusing references with pointers.  C++ has 3 common ways of representing object handles

- References
- Pointers
- Values

Coming from Java the most analogous way is to do so with a pointer.  This is likely what you are trying to do here.

How they are stored though has some pretty fundamental effects on their behaviors.  When you store as a value you are often dealing with copies of the values.  Where pointers are dealing with one object with multiple references.  Giving a flat answer of one is better than the other is not really possible without a bit more context on what these objects do

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on what you want to do... but you're misguided in some ways.

Things you should know are:

1. You can't set a reference to NULL in C++, though you can set a pointer to NULL.
2. A reference can only be made to an existing object - it must start initialized as such.
3. A reference cannot be changed (though the referenced value can be).
4. You wouldn't save space, in fact you would use more since you're using an object and a reference.  If you need to reference the same object multiple times then you save space, but you might as well use a pointer - it's more flexible in MOST (read: not all) scenarios.
5. A last important one: STL containers (vector, list, etc) have COPY semantics - they cannot work with references.  They can work with pointers, but it gets complicated, so for now you should always use copyable objects in those containers and accept that they will be copied, like it or not.  The STL is designed to be efficient and safe with copy semantics.

Hope that helps! :)

PS (EDIT): You can use some new features in BOOST/TR1 (google them), and make a container/array of shared_ptr (reference counting smart pointers) which will give you a similar feel to Java's references and garbage collection.  There's a flurry of differences but you'll have to read about it yourself - they are a great feature of the new standard.

Comment: "should I just store pointers to the objects or is it better to store the object itself?"

Comment: His original question never mentioned a pointer, it mentioned references everywhere trying to treat them as they would be used in Java which isn't possible. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should always store objects when possible; that way, the container will manage the objects' lifetimes for you.

Occasionally, you will need to store pointers; most commonly, pointers to a base class where the objects themselves will be of different types. In that case, you need to be careful to manage the lifetime of the objects yourself; ensuring that they are not destroyed while in the container, but that they are destroyed once they are no longer needed.

Unlike Java, setting a pointer to null does *not* deallocate the object pointed to; instead, you get a memory leak if there are no more pointers to the object. If the object was created using `new`, then `delete` must be called at some point. Your best options here are to store smart pointers (`shared_ptr`, or perhaps `unique_ptr` if available), or to use Boost's pointer containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store references in a container. You could store (naked) pointers instead, but that's prone to errors and is therefore frowned upon.

Thus, the real choice is between storing objects and smart pointers to objects. Both have their uses. My recommendation would be to go with storing objects by value unless the particular situation demands otherwise. This could happen:

- if you need to NULL out the object without removing it from the
  container;
- if you need to store pointers to the same object in
  multiple containers;
- if you need to treat elements of the container
  polymorphically.

One reason to **not** do it is to save space, since storing elements by value is likely to be more space-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of aix:

If you want to store polymorphic objects, you must use smart pointers because the containers make a copy, and for derived types only copy the base part (at least the standard ones, I think boost has some containers which work differently). Therefore you'll lose any polymorphic behaviour (and any derived-class state) of your objects.